# Is there a way to read from a website, one line at a time?

Tags: c#

I have this code:

```
string downloadedString;
System.Net.WebClient client;

client = new System.Net.WebClient();

downloadedString = client.DownloadString(
     "http://thebnet.x10.mx/HWID/BaseHWID/AlloweHwids.txt");
```

It's a HWID-type security (it will check your HWID to see if you are allowed to use the program)

Anyway, I want to be able to put multiple lines on it at a time, example:

```
xjh94jsl <-- Not a real HWID
t92jfgds <-- Also not real
```

And be able to read each line, one by one, and update it to downloadedString.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Don't download the url as a string, read it as a stream.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;

var url ="http://thebnet.x10.mx/HWID/BaseHWID/AlloweHwids.txt";
var client = new WebClient();
using (var stream = client.OpenRead(url))
using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need a reference to use this?

Comment: I don't know. It keeps giving me an error that it's missing an assembly reference to use StreamReader and WebClient.

Comment: Oh, those are in different namespaces.  `StreamReader` is in the `System.IO` namespace and `WebClient` is in the `System.Net` namespace.  Just add `using` directives at the top of your file and you should be golden.

Comment: Does this also download the file one line at a time, or all at once?

Comment: @orad: You're streaming it in but only processing the data one line at a time. I believe it will download all that it can fit into a buffer and only read more as you read, but I don't know for sure.